# Ponteiros com variaveis float e char

Tags: c, ponteiro

Não estou conseguindo atribuir um endereço a uma variável ponteiro quando se trata de variáveis do tipo float ou char, o visual studio me traz o erro "C++ a value of type cannot be assigned to an entity of type".
Com a variavel int o apontamento funciona normalmente, no caso minha variável int x está ok, agora a float y e char z da problema conforme abaixo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    //Declaração das variaveis e inicialização.
    int x = 12; 
    float y = 22.20;
    char z = 'u';

    int *ponteiro_x, *ponteiro_y, *ponteiro_z; //declaração dos ponteiros

        ponteiro_x = &x; //ok
        ponteiro_y = &y; //erro
        ponteiro_z = &z; // erro


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Sim, você definiu onteiro_x, ponteiro_y e ponteiro_z como ponteiro para int, por isso só `ponteiro_x = &x;` está correto. Declare `float*ponteiro_y; char *ponteiro_z;`que ficará correto.

Answer (score 4):

Conforme o colega @anonimo comentou, o erro em seu código está na declaracao dos tipos de ponteiros.

Se voce possui uma variavel y do tipo float, voce precisa criar um ponteiro do tipo float. A mesma coisa se aplica ao char z. Em seu código, voce definiu como int todos os ponteiros, mas o certo é definir os ponteiros de acordo com cada tipo de variavel que voce possui, conforme codigo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
//Declaração das variaveis e inicialização.
int x = 12; 
float y = 22.20;
char z = 'u';

int *ponteiro_x; //declaração do ponteiro da variavel x
float *ponteiro_y; //declaração do ponteiro da variavel y
char *ponteiro_z; //declaração do ponteiro da variavel z

    ponteiro_x = &x; //ok
    ponteiro_y = &y; // irá funcionar.
    ponteiro_z = &z; // irá funcionar.


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```